# windows update fails on windows vista x64 because of KB980182

Tags: windows-vista, windows-update

I believe a corrupt install of KB980182 for windows vista x64 is causing windows update to fail. As a result I cannot run windows update, or install/uninstall updates via the control panel. I have run the readiness tool which includes checksur, and I've received the following output.

Does anyone know how I might be able to rectify this situation without a repair install/in place upgrade?

I understand it might be possible to extract KB980182 and copy the files to the packages folder and this might fix the situation but I haven't worked out how to do this yet.

```
=================================
Checking System Update Readiness.
Binary Version 6.0.6002.22441
Package Version 9.0

Checking Windows Servicing Packages

Checking Package Manifests and Catalogs

Checking Package Watchlist

Checking Component Watchlist

Checking Packages
(f) CBS MUM Missing 0x00000002 servicing\Packages\Package_2_for_KB980182~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.mum  
(f) CBS MUM Missing 0x00000002 servicing\Packages\Package_5_for_KB980182~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.mum  
(f) CBS MUM Missing 0x00000002 servicing\Packages\Package_6_for_KB980182~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.mum  
(f) CBS Registry Error 0x80070002 Package_for_KB980182_client_0~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2  failed to get CurrentState
(f) CBS Registry Error 0x80070002 Package_for_KB980182_client_0~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2  failed to get Visibility
(f) CBS MUM Missing 0x00000002 servicing\Packages\Package_for_KB980182_client_0~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.mum  
(f) CBS MUM Missing 0x00000002 servicing\Packages\Package_for_KB980182_client_1~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.mum  
(f) CBS MUM Missing 0x00000002 servicing\Packages\Package_for_KB980182_client_2~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.mum  
(f) CBS MUM Missing 0x00000002 servicing\Packages\Package_for_KB980182_client~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.mum  
(f) CBS MUM Missing 0x00000002 servicing\Packages\Package_for_KB980182~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.mum  

Checking Component Store

Summary:
Seconds executed: 2195
 Found 10 errors
  CBS MUM Missing Total count: 8
  CBS Registry Error Total count: 2

Unavailable repair files:
 servicing\packages\Package_2_for_KB980182~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.mum
 servicing\packages\Package_5_for_KB980182~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.mum
 servicing\packages\Package_6_for_KB980182~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.mum
 servicing\packages\Package_for_KB980182_client_0~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.mum
 servicing\packages\Package_for_KB980182_client_1~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.mum
 servicing\packages\Package_for_KB980182_client_2~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.mum
 servicing\packages\Package_for_KB980182_client~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.mum
 servicing\packages\Package_for_KB980182~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.mum
 servicing\packages\Package_2_for_KB980182~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.cat
 servicing\packages\Package_5_for_KB980182~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.cat
 servicing\packages\Package_6_for_KB980182~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.cat
 servicing\packages\Package_for_KB980182_client_0~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.cat
 servicing\packages\Package_for_KB980182_client_1~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.cat
 servicing\packages\Package_for_KB980182_client_2~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.cat
 servicing\packages\Package_for_KB980182_client~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.cat
 servicing\packages\Package_for_KB980182~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.1.2.cat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a security update for Internet Explorer. My suggestion would be to remove IE completely (so that it reverts back to IE7) and then reinstall IE8 from a standalone installer.

Easiest way to kill IE8 is to visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957700 for details.

Answer (score 0):

Use  Microsoft System Restore, pick a date before you installed the problem KB

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-system-restore/